# Printing pdf in android

Tags: android-wifi, android-wireless

Is there any common sdk , library etc which can connect phone or tab to any printer(any compony) through wifi and able to print out pdf? I dont want to use app like epson iprint cause I have to integrate it and cloud printing is not an option?

Comment: Have you got any solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

I also search solution for print PDF from my application on Epson matrix printer. You can try this code, that code work well for HP network laser printer:

```
File pdfFile = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testPdf.pdf");

Socket clientSocket = null;
FileInputStream fis;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;

try {
    clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.101.45", 9100);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int) pdfFile.length()];
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    os.flush();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        clientSocket.close();
        bis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have big problem with printing PDF from Android. Android almost don't have drivers for printers.

This code open stream on certain socket where you printer connect. We have big and good HP laser printer and with this code PDF file prints well.
But our users don't have that good printers :)

Now we use PDF like print preview but for print we use text with printer sequence. That approach for creating document can be very difficult. You must create text file with print sequence for your printer, then, you may with this code set to printer:

```
outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
outToServer.writeUTF(stringForPrint);
outToServer.flush();
```

You may add tags (like HTML ) in your text file and before sent text to printer, you can replace tags with sequence:

```
        // bold on
        text = text.replaceAll("<B>", Character.toString((char)27) + "E");
        // bold off
        text = text.replaceAll("</B>", Character.toString((char)27) + "F");
```

I read (didn't try) that maybe if you PDF (image) can convert to PostScript and sent PostScript file on printer and if printer support PostScript maybe PDF will print well.
Also I view that maybe GhostScript can help for convert. Good luck :)