# Printing PDF with Android

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a PDF from within my android application. But everytime i try to print my printed page contains weird data like:

```
  java.io.FileInputStream@418479b0
```

I assume that my pdf isn't being rendered in the correct way...
Does anybody now how i can correctly convert my pdf to my outputstream?

I already tried the code from this question([Printing pdf in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017529/printing-pdf-in-android)), but then i get following output on my printed page:

```
   Filter/FlateDecode/Length 69 >>stream
```

Can anybody help me? :)

This is my code:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    String sIP = "192.168.0.250";
    String sPort = "9100";

    InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(sIP, Integer.parseInt(sPort));
    DataOutputStream outputStream;

    try{
        //file init
        File pdfFile = new File(file);
        byte[] byteArray=null;
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
        String inputStreamToString = inputStream.toString();
        byteArray = inputStreamToString.getBytes();
        inputStream.close();

        //Socket init
        socket.connect(socketAddress, 3000);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.write(byteArray);
        outputStream.close();
        socket.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to get the byteArray:

```
//file init
File pdfFile = new File(file);
byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) pdfFile.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
fis.read(byteArray);
fis.close();
```

Comment: if i try this, my printer doesn't want to print, but i also don't get an error or something...